# Combining two objects with volume materials

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, volumetrics

I would like to create a volume material with two channels: red and green. For each channel I have corresponding voxel data. I tried to create two separate objects and overlay them, but standard blender render fails to do that (cycles, as I know, doesn't even support voxel data). What are my options?

[image: Two volumes separated]
[image: Two volumes overlayed]

[image]

For some reason, blender didn't include voxel files. Here [they are](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hbE5lBp-vojgyMobv_0iJdzUwN-2qgYV/view?usp=sharing) (128×128×128).

Comment: Looks like there are emission shaders in each cube. Add them together in single material on a single cube?

Comment: Thanks! But I after a lot of trials I still have no idea how to do it. How do you mix two volume textures in one material?

Comment: With the *Add Shader*, if you add screenshot of node setups of your materials I can post an example adding them as an answer.

Comment: When I click “use nodes” it switches to surface rendering somehow and I can only see the volume texture through the other box. (https://i.imgur.com/0mpSe54.png) I have no idea how to make nodes work with voxel textures in the first place.

Comment: Oh you are using Blender Render and not Cycles. My bad, I missed the tag. Then you have a material with Voxel Data or Point Density texture. Make a single material with 2 volumetric textures and set the *blend* parameter to *Add* (it's under influence of each texture).